# Reading array of strings from file with Apache Pig

Tags: arrays, hadoop, apache-pig

I'm storing a Hive table externally, and it's a pretty simple data structure.  The table is created in Hive as

```
(user string, names array<string>)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\001'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

(I've tried other delimiters, too).

In Pig, I can't seem to figure out the right way to use a bag or tuple to just load a simple array!  Here's what I've tried without luck:

```
users = load '<file>' using PigStorage() AS (user:chararray, names:bag{tuple(name:chararray)})

users = load '<file>' using PigStorage() AS (user:chararray, names:chararray)
```

and some other things, but the best I've gotten was to have them loaded as a single string with the delimiter removed (which doesn't help).  How do I just load a variable-length array of strings?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say you have the following data in the /user/hdfs/tester/ip/test file on HDFS

```
cat test:
1   A,B
2   C,D,E,F
3   G
4   H,I,J,K,L,M
```

In Pig Mapreduce do the following:

```
a = LOAD '/user/hdfs/tester/ip/test' USING PigStorage('\t') as (id:INT,names:chararray);
b = FOREACH a GENERATE id, FLATTEN(TOBAG(STRSPLIT(names,','))) as value:tuple(name:CHARARRAY);
```

The first column is id and value is the tuple of CHARARRAY.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like FLATTEN(TOBAG()), but string splitting was the obvious answer that I was too boneheaded to use.  Thank you!

I still ended up with a problem of then not being able to define the schema to inject this into Mongo, and had to add a value to the string 'keys' so that I could define the schema with a bag of tupples and thus inject it to mongo (since the connector really prefers a schema).  Silly PIG needs basic arrays! (in my opinion)

Comment: I have my data in this format: `{"id": "59b6808364fdb09cde10ad3b","balance": "$1,972.02","age": 35,"eyeColor": "green","tags": ["aute","nostrud","pariatur","adipisicing","irure"]}`. What must be the related PIG script for loading tags column? I tried `tags:chararray` but did not help.